# Prove that the image of a ring via functor is a bimodule

Tags: category-theory, modules, functors

I'm studying Morita theory on "Rings and Categories of Modules", Anderson.
I have some problems with a Theorem about equivalent rings.

Let $R$ and $S$ be equivalent rings via inverse equivalences $F: {}_{R}Mod \to {}_{S}Mod$ and $G: {}_{S}Mod \to {}_{R}Mod$. Set $P=F(R)$, $Q=G(S)$.
Then $P$ and $Q$ are naturally bimodules $_{S}P_{R}$ and $_{R}Q_{S}$.

The theorem states other results but I can't demonstrate this first assertion.
In the proof he uses two isomorphisms
$R \cong End(_{R}R)$ via right multiplication $\lambda$ for a scalar in $R$ and $End(_{R}R) \cong End(_{S}P)$ via $F$.
So there is a ring isomorphism $r \mapsto F(\lambda(r))$ and I have to use this one to define a right multiplication of an element of $P$ for a scalar in $R$ to prove that $P$ is a right $R$-module. He also says that we use the fact that $_{R}R_{R}$ is a bimodule and that $F$ is an additive functor.

I have thought of:
$P\times R \to P$ sending $(p,r) \mapsto pF(\lambda(r))$ but i'm not sure of this definition and if the result is in P. How can I prove that P is a right R-module? 
If someone has some suggestions I'd really appreciate!

Comment: Actually it's $R^{op}$ that is isomorphic to $End(_R R)$, so if $f:R^{op}\to End(_S P)$ is your isomorphism, can't you define $x\cdot \lambda = f(\lambda)(x)$ ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are saying. Can you try to explain?

Comment: An endomorphism of $_R R$ is of the form $x\mapsto xa$ for some $a$: indeed put $a=f(1)$, then for $x\in R$, $f(x) = f(x 1) = xf(1)$. But $g:a\mapsto (x\mapsto xa)$ is not a morphism: indeed $g(ab) : x\mapsto xab = (xa)b = g(b)(xa) = g(b)\circ g(a)(x)$. It's rather a morphism from the opposite ring (that has multiplication defined as $x\times^{op}y= yx$) to $End(_R R)$. So you have an isomorphism $f:R^{op}\to End(_S P)$. Use this to define the *right* action of $R$ on $P$ by $x\cdot \lambda= f(\lambda)(x)$, for $x\in P, \lambda \in R$

Comment: This will indeed be a bimodule structure because each $f(\lambda)$ is $S$-linear

Comment: Are the 2 isomorphisms in the text right? Isn't the composition of two isomorphisms an isomorphism?

Comment: The first one you mention is wrong if $R$ is not commutative: $R$ is not isomorphic to $End(_R R)$ in general. It is if and only if it is isomorphic to $R^{op}$: there are examples in which it's not the case

Comment: thanks, I was sure because the author states this isomorphism in the book and then he uses it in this proof.

Comment: The author probably uses the isomorphism with $R^{op}$ rather: doesn't the text say "anti-isomorphism" or something along these lines ?

Comment: I'll search back in the text when he introduces the notation. With your help however it's clearer, tthanks!